# How to use Rules and conditions in UpdateAttributes processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

i'm new to nifi.

How to perform rules and actions in Advanced Tab in updateProcessor?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how new you are, I'd first suggest watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgTGAWLC170) on the basics of creating a flow in NiFi (it's old but conveys the essentials).

After you can already create a flow using the basic functionality of UpdateAttribute, the best place to start learning about the advanced functionality is the "[Additional Details](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html)" section of the UpdateAttribute doc. It should cover everything you need to get started with the Advanced tab of UpdateAttribute.

Comment: I can able to use update attribute processor with some regular expression and well known its uses. But need to know how to give rules and actions in it.

Comment: Is it possible to use "If Statement" in Rules?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but the rules are a series of "If Statements". If the conditions set in the top box of the advanced view are met then the actions in the bottom box are executed. That is explained in the "Advanced Usage" section of the doc I linked.